# Automatically place braces like Visual Studio

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use braces in Visual Studio, I press Enter and the brackets are automatically positioned like this:

[image: typing brackets with visual studio]

When I use them in IntelliJ, I have to apply formatting (Ctrl+Alt+L) to make them move:

[image: typing brackets with intellij and adjusting format]

Is it possible to get this behaviour in IntelliJ? I don't want to have to spam autoformat to make my code the way I want.

It's worth noting that I've specified that my brackets go on the next line in settings:

[image: intellij settings]

Comment: Is the second example C# or Java? If it's Java then _not_ having the opening `{` on a separate line would be considered "looking normal".

Comment: It's Java, but we like what we like.

Comment: Not sure how to get IntelliJ to do this formatting for you automatically as you type. But it should fix the formatting for you according to your Code Style settings if you press `Ctrl + Alt + l`

Answer (score 0):

Filled the bug request to IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286306

Feel free to follow.

For the time being, you can toggle reformat manually.